# Generating function for runs in alphabets

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, combinatorics-on-words

Let $\mathcal{J}$ be a finite set of letters. Suppose that $|\mathcal{J}| = m$. Now designate a letter from the set $\mathcal{J}$. What is the ordinary generating function of words with letters from $\mathcal{J}$ without $k$ consecutive occurrences of the  designated letter. For the case $m=2$ the generating function is easily seen to be $$ \dfrac{1-z^k}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}$$

However I am having difficulty in finding the generating funcution for arbitrary $m$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The languages you're describing are [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), which means they admits rational generating functions. Indeed, we can read the generating function off of a regular expression for the language.

For example, if $k=3$ and $m=2$, the language (where we cannot repeat $a$) is described by

$$(b + ab + aab)^* (1 + a + aa)$$

We can read off from this a generating function

$$\frac{1 + a + a^2}{1 - (b + ab + a^2 b)}$$

(using the fact that $L^* = 1 + L + L^2 + \ldots = \frac{1}{1-L}$).

It turns out the coefficient of $a^nb^m$ in the above series is exactly the number of words using $n$ $a$s and $m$ $b$s! So if we only care about the length, we can just replace every letter by one variable $z$. This gives us

$$\frac{1 + z + z^2}{1 - z - z^2 - z^3}$$

and taylor expanding this gives the correct sequence.

---

Now that we have the basics down, let's do this in general. For $m$ letters $a_1, \ldots a_m$, say we want to avoid $k$ consecutive copies of $a_1$. Then our language is given by:

$$
\left (
1 + a_1 + a_1^2 + \ldots + a_1^{k-1}
\right )
\left [
  \left ( 
    \sum_{i=2}^m a_i
  \right )^+ 
  \left ( a_1 + a_1^2 + \ldots + a_1^{k-1} \right )
\right ]^* 
\left ( \sum_{i=2}^m a_i \right )^*
$$

(do you see why?)

Since we only care about the total number, we again substitute $z$ for each variable, then cash out the kleene stars for $\frac{1}{1-L}$s and get

$$
\frac{1 + z + z^2 + \ldots + z^{k-1}}{1 - (m-1)z - (m-1)z^2 - \ldots - (m-1)z^k}
$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Nice explanation, Thanks.

Comment: (+1) If you multiply the numerator and denominator by $1-z$, I believe our answers match.

Comment: @robjohn -- I think you're right, and the procedure we used to get here was similar too. You can tell it was late when I wrote this, because I actually considered multiplying top and bottom by $1-z$ to clean up the answer, but didn't trust myself to do it correctly in the moment :P

Answer (score 2):

**The Component Generating Functions**

The generating function for the number of choices for (possibly empty) runs of $j$ of the $m-1$ unrestricted letters is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty(m-1)^jx^j=\frac1{1-(m-1)x}\tag{1a}
$$
For non-empty runs of the unrestricted letters, we subtract $1$:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty(m-1)^jx^j=\frac{(m-1)x}{1-(m-1)x}\tag{1b}
$$
The generating function for the number of choices for (possibly empty) runs of $j$ of the restricted letter is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}x^j=\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}\tag{2a}
$$
For non-empty runs of the restricted letter, we subtract $1$:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}x^j=\frac{x-x^k}{1-x}\tag{2b}
$$

**Combining the Components**

The general string starts with a (possibly empty) string of the restricted letter:
$$
\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}\tag3
$$
followed by a (possibly empty) repetition of a non-empty string of the unrestricted letters followed by a non-empty string of the restricted letter:
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(m-1)x}{1-(m-1)x}\frac{x-x^k}{1-x}\right)^j=\frac1{1-\frac{(m-1)x}{1-(m-1)x}\frac{x-x^k}{1-x}}\tag4
$$
followed by a (possibly empty) string of the unrestricted letters:
$$
\frac1{1-(m-1)x}\tag5
$$
Thus, the full generating function is
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}\frac1{1-\frac{(m-1)x}{1-(m-1)x}\frac{x-x^k}{1-x}}\frac1{1-(m-1)x}\tag{6a}\\
&=\frac{1-x^k}{(1-(m-1)x)(1-x)-(m-1)x\left(x-x^k\right)}\tag{6b}\\
&=\frac{1-x^k}{1-mx+(m-1)x^{k+1}}\tag{6c}
\end{align}
$$
$\text{(6c)}$ is the generating function for the number of strings of a given length composed of letters from an $m$ letter alphabet where one restricted letter does not appear in any substring of $k$ consecutive letters.

Answer (score 1):

A convenient starting point is also the generating function of words with no consecutive equal characters at all. These words are called *Smirnov* or *Carlitz* words. See for example III.24 *Smirnov words* in *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.

The generating function for the number of Smirnov words over an $m$-ary alphabet is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{mz}{1+z}\right)^{-1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
In the current problem a designated character may have runs with length $< k$. We respect this by replacing the designated character by
\begin{align*}
z\to z+z^2+\cdots +z^{k-1}=\frac{z-z^{k}}{1-z}\tag{2.1}
\end{align*}
Since there are no restrictions to other characters we can replace each occurrence of these characters by one or more occurrences of it.
\begin{align*}
z\longrightarrow z+z^2+\cdots=\frac{z}{1-z}\tag{2.2}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (1) by substituting (2.1) and (2.2)
> \begin{align*}
> &\left(1-\frac{(m-1)\frac{z}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z}{1-z}}-\frac{\frac{z-z^k}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z-z^k}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}\\
> &\qquad=\left(1-(m-1)z-\frac{z-z^k}{1-z^k}\right)^{-1}\tag{3.1}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{1-z^k}{1-z^k-(m-1)z\left(1-z^k\right)-\left(z-z^k\right)}\tag{3.2}\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1-z^k}{1-mz+(m-1)z^{k+1}}}\tag{3.3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3.1) we expand numerator and denominator with $1-z$.
- In (3.2) we use $1-z^k$ as common denominator.
- In (3.3) we do some final simplifications.